# Use autoref with minted and its listing environment

Tags: hyperref, minted

I would like to use `autoref` from the `hyperref` package to create a reference to a floating listing as provided by minted. This code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
Take a look at the code in \autoref{lst:mylisting}.
\begin{listing}[htb]
  \begin{minted}{erlang}
    foo
    bar
  \end{minted}
  \caption{My listing}
  \label{lst:mylisting}
\end{listing}
\end{document}
```

should produce something like `Listing 1.1` with a link around it.
I don't want to use `Listing~\ref{lst:mylisting}`, because it wouldn't be consistent with all the other links produced by `autoref`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The trick is to define a macro called `\listingname` or `\listingautorefname` which stores the name `hyperref` should use for the reference. In your case, adding the line

```
\providecommand*{\listingautorefname}{Listing}
```

produces correct references.

Comment: This doesn't seam to be necessary anymore

Comment: sure? I had the exact same problem and my environment is up to date.

Comment: This still seems to be necessary using MacTeX 2013

Answer (score 5):

### `\usepackage{listings}`

In case you use `\usepackage{listings}`, instead of `\usepackage{minted}` use this:

##### a) Change caption and reference

Change the caption to `Code 1.1: Blablabla` and the reference to `see foo in Code 1.1`.

```latex
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Code}
```

##### b) Change only reference

The caption remains unchanged, `Listing 1.1: Blablabla`, but the reference will change to `see foo in code 1.1`.

```latex
\providecommand*{\lstlistingautorefname}{code}
```